# center image in thumbnail

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

This is what I have (the images inside an anchor): 
[image] 
And I want that low res images will be centered like this: (edited with paint) 
[image]

This is the razor view:

```
<div>
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="thumbnail centerThumb" style="height:345px; width:280px;margin-bottom:15px">
                <div style="height:125px; ">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Items", new { id = item.ItemID})">
                        <img src="~/Content/thumbnails/@item.Img" alt="thmbnail" width="255" class="img-rounded centerThumb">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h3>
                    <p style="height:95px">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>
                    <p style="position:fixed">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin-left:50%"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price) </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give the URL of the page?

Comment: [Link to page](http://rubik.gear.host/shop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the 4th element using `:nth-child`

```
.col-md-3:nth-child(4) .thumbnail.centerThumb img {
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: I have added that to the css file where `.centerThumb` exist, and it's still not working, what else I need to do ?

Comment: It does center the small res image but all the other images are getting out of the thumbnail [updated code](http://prntscr.com/73k51s)

Comment: That worked, but I'm pretty sure that there are going to be more items coming ahead and the 4th thing will be not so good. It's will be good for meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

This css make your image at center.

```
.centerThumb {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

But as per the web page, your image has some padding after the text. Remove the padding of the image using paint. then it will work for you.